# Why does qRegisterMetaType throw me an error?

Tags: c++, qt, qtserialport

I'm currently working with Qt in order to build an app able to send and receive data packets connected through `QSerialPort`.

For that, I have an object interfacing the communication between my app and the device.

In this class, I can call a run member function, which initiate the communication.

In that method, the connection is like this :

```
qRegisterMetaType<QSerialPort::SerialPortError>();
connect(this->_serialPort, SIGNAL(error(QSerialPort::SerialPortError)), this->_parent,
SLOT(handleSerialError(QSerialPort::SerialPortError)), Qt::QueuedConnection);
```

Here, my problem is that no matter what I tried, I always get an error from the included file from `QtCore`, `qglobal.h`, on the line 684, referring to the first line of code where I try to register the meta type `SerialPortError`.

**The error :**

> Type is not registered, please use the Q_DECLARE_METATYPE macro to
>   make it known to Qt's meta-object system.

And that's what I did! From everywhere in my code, inside the class, inside the name space, or even in global, I called that macro `Q_DECLARE_METATYPE(QSerialPort::SerialPortError)`, but nothing was going well :/

That's my third day looking on the web to solve this error, and  I'm running out of time.

I can not figure out what I'm doing wrong or misunderstanding.

Can someone help me? Have you already faced that error?

Thanks you, David

Comment: Shouldn't you have `Q_DECLARE_METATYPE(QSerialPort::SerialPortError)` instead of `Q_DECLARE_METATYPE(QSerialPort)`?

Comment: That's what i did in the code, i edit my post.

Comment: qRegisterMetaType is for class or struct registration. QSerialPort should be part of QtMeta since it allready use SIGNALS. you don't need to register it.

Comment: In addition, when i do put this macro in my object, i keep the two others errors related to the impossibility to declare the type, but i get 3 more errors concerning template declaration. "explicit specialization in non namespace scope of the class".

Then when i call the macro in the namespace scope, i get 39 errors from undefined reference. I guess that's the good way, but as i keep getting some errors into the included .h about my list of serial ports, i'm not totally sure. The fact is that this code is not mine, and i'm not allowed to show it on any website --'

Comment: What type is `QSerialPort::SerialPortError`? Is it an enum?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`QSerialPort` inherits `QObject`, so the error type enum should already be registered via `Q_ENUMS`. You don't need to re-register.

Comment: I guess you are right, as i just totally deleted it,and it now prints me others errors, the ones about the undefined reference to _imp__ZN15QSerialPortInfo[...]. I'm looking forward this way, if can get over it, i'll resolve my post, otherwise i'll keep it alive and updated. Thanks you

Answer (score -1):

I had this same error and i managed to fix it without using the Q_DECLARE_METATYPE.

have you tried: `qRegisterMetaType<QSerialPort>();`

because all i had to do in my code was just that... just register the class. Even though it was giving me the same error, telling me to use Q_DECLARE_METATYPE.

Comment: yes i realize that. But from my experience, sometimes a small adjustment can fix things up just the way you need it... so i am suggesting calling the qRegisterMetaType on QSerialPort instead of QSerialPort::SerialPortError

Comment: yes, that's what we did in a first place. I'm still looking for the undefined reference to im_ZN15QSerialPortInfo, the doc about it, if it exists, is not really usefull to me